# Rails migration で主キーの有無を判定したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql

本番にだけ存在するPKを別環境にも作成するマイグレーションを作りたいのですが
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html
これを見る感じPK関連のメソッドはマイグレーションクラスに用意されていなくて
生SQLを叩くしかないでしょうか

作るだけなら以下のSQLでできそうなのですが
「本番ですでに存在する」というのがネックで
あったら何もしないなかったら作成ということをするにはどういうコードを書けばいいでしょうか

```
class AddPkToApiAccessCounts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    execute 'ALTER TABLE api_access_counts ADD PRIMARY KEY (`date_string`,`group_id`,`date_time_minutes`)'
  end
end
```

今回はおきかえるわけではないのでPKの有無さえ判定できればいいのですが
よろしくおねがいします

Answer (score 0):

あまりきれいな方法じゃないんですが無理やりDDLの中の文字列を探して判定して一応実現できました
もっといい方法や問題があったら指摘してもらえると助かります

```
class AddPkToApiAccessCounts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # DDL を取得して PK が存在しない場合のみ作成
    pk_statement = 'PRIMARY KEY (`date_string`,`group_id`,`date_time_minutes`)'
    result = select_one('SHOW CREATE TABLE api_access_counts')
    ddl = result['Create Table']
    if !ddl.include?(pk_statement)
      execute "ALTER TABLE api_access_counts ADD #{pk_statement}"
    end
  end
end
```